# Passed Fortran array shape changes in function

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have an array declared and populated in a program block that is being passed to a function inside a module. However, the shape of the array in the program block is different from the shape in the function block which leads to errors in practice. Here's some cut down code for illustration:

```
program prgQuad
    use modPoint2D, only: Point2D
    use modQuadrature, only : QuadIntegrateTri2D
    implicit none

    ! the array in question
    type( Point2D ), dimension( : ) :: pts( 1: 3 )
    real :: res

        ! populate the points
        call pts( 1 ) % set( 0.0, 0.0 )
        call pts( 2 ) % set( 1.0, 0.0 )
        call pts( 3 ) % set( 1.0, 1.0 )

        write( *, * ) shape( pts ) ! prints '3'

        ! use the points
        res = QuadIntegrateTri2D( pts )

end program prgQuad
```

In modQuadrature:

```
function QuadIntegrateTri2D( pts ) result( integral )
    class( Point2D ), dimension( : ), intent( in ) :: pts( 1: 3 )
    real :: integral
    ! other vars go here

        write( *, * ) shape( pts ) ! prints '4'

        ! actual function code goes here 

end function QuadIntegrateTri2D( pts )
```

Surely I'm missing something. I have no idea why the shape of the array would change. I know Fortran passes by reference so the program block and the function are looking at the same block of memory. Any insight as to why the shape changes is appreciated! Thanks.

modPoint2D:

```
module modPoint2D

    type Point2D
        real( rp ) :: x, y
    contains
        procedure :: set => SetPoint2D
    end type

contains

    subroutine SetPoint2D( self, x, y )
        class( Point2D ), intent( out) :: self
        real( rp ),       intent( in )  :: x, y

            self % x = x
            self % y = y

    end subroutine SetPoint2D

end module modPoint2D
```

Comment: Have you compiled with all checking options, to ensure that there's no dodgy access somewhere?  Beyond that, can you prepare a complete example for us?  See [mcve].

Comment: That's very peculiar.  But it's also peculiar that you have 2 specifications of the size/shape of the function argument `pts`.  Usually we (old Fortran programmers) just specify it once, e.g. `class(Point2D), dimension(:), intent(in) :: pts` -- as an *assumed-shape* argument.

Comment: It should be noted that the dummy argument `pts` is like `pts(1:3)` entirely independently of the entity called `pts` in the main program (as long as that latter has at least three elements).  So, if `shape(pts)` in that function is giving a different result there's a bug either in the compiler or in the code somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, all. I modified my function to take in `real, intent( in ) :: pts( 1: 3 )` and the correct shape was reported. Then I modified it take `type( Point2D), intent( in ) :: pts( 1: 3 )` rather than `class( Point2D )` and the function again reported the correct shape. So I believe I have narrowed this down to a `class` identifier issue. I am compiling with gfortran in gcc 6.1.0.

Comment: can you please include the definition of `set()`

Comment: What is `rp`?  In particular, does it correspond to the kind of default real?  [I guess it does, as the compiler isn't complaining.]

Comment: `use iso_fortran_env; integer, parameter :: rp = REAL64` `rp` is just a `kind` specification to control precision.

Comment: [You could have `use intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : rp=>real64.`]  But are you sure that `real` and `real(real64)` are the same thing?  What if you try `call pts(1)%set(0.0_rp, 0.0_rp)`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `pts` is very peculiar indeed. The code below compiles and runs as intended with the correct shape for the array of points.

```
module modPoint2D

    type :: Point2D
        real :: x,y
    contains
        procedure, pass :: set
    end type
    contains

    subroutine set(pnt, px, py)
    class(Point2D), intent(out) :: pnt
    real, intent(in) :: px, py

        pnt%x = px
        pnt%y = py

    end subroutine
end module


module modQuadrature
use modPoint2D

    contains
    function QuadIntegrateTri2D( pts ) result( integral )
        class( Point2D ), dimension( : ), intent( in ) :: pts
        real :: integral
        ! other vars go here

            write( *, * ) shape( pts ) ! prints '3'

            ! actual function code goes here 
            integral = 0

    end function 
end module


program prgQuad
    use modPoint2D, only: Point2D
    use modQuadrature, only : QuadIntegrateTri2D
    implicit none

    ! the array in question
    type( Point2D ), dimension(:) :: pts(1:3)
    real :: res

        call pts( 1 ) % set( 0.0, 0.0 )
        call pts( 2 ) % set( 1.0, 0.0 )
        call pts( 3 ) % set( 1.0, 1.0 )

        write( *, * ) shape( pts ) ! prints '3'

        ! use the points
        res = QuadIntegrateTri2D( pts )

end program
```

Comment: Are you saying that with your complete example, having `class( Point2D ), dimension( : ), intent( in ) :: pts(1:3)` exhibits the problem of the question?

Comment: `type( Point2D ), dimension(:):: pts(1:3)` in the main program produces the correct output. I'll edit the answer. There is no reason to specify `class( Point2D ), dimension( : ), intent( in ) :: pts(1:3)` in `QuadIntegrateTri2D()`